# RCP 4 Add Custom MPart directly to MWindow

Tags: java, rcp

I am trying to add a banner to an application and saw in another forum that one way to do this in RCP4 is to "put a custom part directly in the MWindow".  I'm not exactly sure how to do this and don't understand what classes need to hook together to make this work (since that option is not available via the xmi file).  Can someone provide sample code to show how this would be achieved?

Comment: I think this is just saying to add a Part to the Controls in your RCP Trimmed Window in the Application.e4xmi

Comment: Unfortunately that adds the part below the menu/toolbar.  I was hoping to place it above it.

Comment: Getting anything above the menu is likely to be very difficult (certainly not possible on a Mac where the menu is always at the very top of the screen).

Comment: Yeah, I am currently looking at overriding the WBWRenderer.  Fun times...